# Is this "stat [option]... inode number..." possible?

Tags: inode, stat

Is it possible to use `stat` for retrieving meta data of `File1` by passing File1's inode number as an argument to `stat` instead of the file name?

```
stat [option - any doing this?] [inode number of File1]
```

instead of

```
stat /home/$USER/File1
```

I mean that directly, not with any piping and command substitution trickery.

Comment: I don't think it will be, for the same reason that opening a file directly via an inode isn't possible - this will bypass access controls on possible ancestor directories and leak metadata.

Comment: Hmm, it seems you asked specifically about the `stat` command and then accepted an answer using the `debugfs` command (which is specific to ext4 filesystems). What's the actual question here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this one?

```bash
sudo debugfs -R "stat <237770>" /dev/sda1
```

For me, it gives me this output:

```
Inode: 237770   Type: regular    Mode:  0644   Flags: 0x80000
Generation: 3934018986    Version: 0x00000000:00000001
User:  1000   Group:  1000   Project:     0   Size: 3878
File ACL: 0
Links: 1   Blockcount: 8
Fragment:  Address: 0    Number: 0    Size: 0
 ctime: 0x65844b48:c3cc9104 -- Thu Dec 21 15:27:20 2023
 atime: 0x65844b4f:d21ab1e8 -- Thu Dec 21 15:27:27 2023
 mtime: 0x65844b48:c3cc9104 -- Thu Dec 21 15:27:20 2023
crtime: 0x6584497f:07719290 -- Thu Dec 21 15:19:43 2023
Size of extra inode fields: 32
Inode checksum: 0x6a9c083c
EXTENTS:
(0):2478609
```

Answer (score 2):

No, by design it's not possible to access a file other than via a path to it, allowing it would bypass access control so that would be a security flaw.

`root` can possibly do that by using tools such as [`debugfs` (for ext4 file systems) on the block device containing the filesystem](/a/767267) (if any) effectively bypassing the kernel to inspect the filesystem structure but doing that on a mounted filesystem is not necessarily reliable; or using kernel instrumentation such as systemtap or bpftrace, though that's likely to be non-portable even between two versions of a given kernel.

So you should use something like:

```
find /root/of/filesystem -xdev -inode 12345 -exec stat {} ';'
```

To find the path(s) leading to that file with that particular inode and call `stat` on them.

With GNU `find`, you can also use `-printf` to report stat(2) information about the file.